# MutableLiveData Object Creation in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to developing application in Xamarin Android. I integrated AndroidX.lifeCycle using nuggets. I know how to create an object private MutableLiveData currentName = new MutableLiveData();
in java Android. but difficult to create an object in Xamarin Android. Any one has idea how to use LiveData in Xamarin Android

Comment: Have you get success of using LiveData in Xamarin Android?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData` nuget.Package first, right click your `Xamarin.Android` project and choose `Manage Nuget Packages..`, then search the package and install it as showed in below screenshot:

[image]

Then in your project, use the namespace and code :

```
using Android.Arch.Lifecycle;

MutableLiveData currentName = new MutableLiveData();
```

**Update**:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MutableLiveData currentName = new MutableLiveData();
        currentName.SetValue("321");

        mylifeCycle lifeCycle = new mylifeCycle();
        mylObserver obsever = new mylObserver();

        currentName.Observe(lifeCycle, obsever);
    }
}


public class mylifeCycle : ILifecycleOwner
{
    public Lifecycle Lifecycle => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class mylObserver : IObserver
{
    public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnChanged(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already the nugget package, but to use generics MuatableliveData<ArrayList<Integer>>

Comment: In java we will create object in private MutableLiveData<String> currentName; same way I need create in xamarin did you have idea object this

Comment: Have you worked in AndroidX paging library in Xamarin Android

Comment: What does MutableLiveData<String> currentName mean? Can you show me the complete code in java?

Comment: can you refer this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: That probably means you set a string value to currentName . Like `currentName.SetValue("321");`.

Comment: Thanks you so much Jack . how to write observer for this pattern

Comment: What does observer  mean here?

Comment: @ANANDPRABHAKAR Did you found any help on it?

Comment: Observer is class to observe the content changes in viewmodel class method

Comment: Did you know how to covert C# object to java.lang.object ? Jack

Comment: Why you need to convert a C# object to java.lang.object? I think you can open a new thread and ask your question there with more detailed information. And if my answer(this answer) helps you, you can mark/upvote it.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  We used Observer with livedata in Java Android. 
``` ViewModel.loadArticle().Observe(this, new Observer(){
   @Override    
   void onChange(Boolean value){
       }
});```
My question is how we use this type of anonymous interface in C#

Comment: See my updated answer, the OnChanged method is under IObserver interface in the mylObserver  class.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT When i created seprated class to implement IObserver then i had to implement alot of method. But noticed in your code you just override two methods. ?

Comment: im using this nuget from xamrain using AndroidX.Lifecycle;

Comment: I use Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData, if you have to  implement a lot of method under AndroidX.Lifecycle, just go and implement it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is caused by the fact that the Xamarin API is referencing java objects.

> When i created seprated class to implement IObserver then i had to implement alot of method. But noticed in your code you just override two methods. ?

That's because IObserver is a java interface. If you inherit from Java.Lang.Object then you just need to implement the one method:

```
    class MyObserver : Java.Lang.Object, IObserver
    {
        public void OnChanged (Java.Lang.Object o)
        {
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could implement IObserver in an existing class that already inherits from Java.Lang.Object, e.g. your Adapter class.

> Did you know how to covert C# object to java.lang.object ?

I think you're refering to the fact that the LiveData object, that is being observed, is a Java.Lang.Object.

In my case I wanted to observe a C# object, specifically a System.Collections.Generic.List. But this is not allowed as there is no way to convert between the System object and a Java object.

My solution was to use an Android.Runtime.JavaList object. This is a Java object *and* implements System.Collections.Generic.IList so I didn't have to go digging into the Java class hierarchy, I just used the C# IList methods.

IMHO the fact that we need to use java objects at all suggests that this is an area that the Xamarin team haven't prioritised.